# How to get autocompletet textbox Locations from google API in mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, google-api

I am using MVC and in View i want to bind a textbox to google API to get auto complete address, How to do this in MVC??
Note: I dont want to display google maps. just textbox show suggestions .. I Did something like this

```
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")


 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAacPaT9YiOu-8leoacd1RDbRfx7an1u74&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>

        <script>

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(AddNewJob, 'load', function () {
                var options = {
                    types: ['(cities)'],
                    componentRestrictions: { country: "in" }
                };
            });

    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('FromAddress'));
    autocomplete.addListener();

 </script>
        }
```

And in textBox

```
         <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FromAddress, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="text" id="FromAddress"  />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FromAddress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        var input = document.getElementById('your input tag id');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
```

Use javascript to do it. Follow [api documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete)

Check it out on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/)

Comment: Did you create api key and include the scripts as shown in the documentation above.

Comment: I created key. Now how to include it in my local project?

Comment: It's in the documentation; copied straight from there. `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>`

Comment: Yes i did that. now how to create function or script in which i can paste above code given by you Sir

Comment: var input = document.getElementById('your input tag id');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

Comment: You should put that inside script tag at the end of your .cshtml page

Comment: I did all but not successful . @Harish Help please

Comment: `var input = document.getElementById('FromAddress');
            var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);` Move these two lines of code outside the listener and add listener to places. The documentation is pretty straight forward.

Comment: I am doing this in Razor view... Is something different in that? I followed almost all steps Sir @Harish

Comment: Doesn't matter if you doing it in razor view or html page.

Comment: Can you post the complete code in answer pane? @Harish

Comment: Sir @Harish I edited my script code in the question. Please check and tell me where i m doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you'll need a Maps API Key which you can obtain here : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/get-api-key.

Replace `YOUR_API_KEY` in the scripts url with the api key you obtain from the link above.

Change the id to match the id of the input element you want to attach this to. In the example below, the input element's id is "FromAddress".

And you might want to change `options` or remove it entirely depending on your needs as the current setting limits the auto-completion to cities in India.

```
@section Scripts {

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&amp;callback=initMap" async="" defer=""></script>

    <script>

        function initMap() {

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
            var options = {
                types: ['(cities)'],
                componentRestrictions: { country: "in" }
            };

            var input = document.getElementById('FromAddress');
                var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

            });

        }


    </script>

}
```